# Trying to solve generics error

Tags: c#, oop, generics, design-patterns

I would like to know how could i initate the BaseDao class ?

```
public class BaseDao<TEntity, TIdentifier>
where TIdentifier : new()
where TEntity : BaseVo<TIdentifier>
{
//has implementation
}

public class BaseVo<TIdentifier>
    where TIdentifier : new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Identifier.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual TIdentifier Id { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to do

```
 public BaseDao<Department, int>  GetDepartmentRepository()
    {
       return new BaseDao<Department, int>();


    }
```

But getting the error - Kindly help
The type 'Domain.Models.Entities.Department' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'Domain.Models.BaseDao'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Domain.Models.Entities.Department' to 'Domain.Models.BaseVo'.

Comment: Does 'Department' derive from 'BaseVO<int>?

Comment: In a case like this to get help faster you should have added the code for the Deparment class, after all it was part of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Department class must be of derived from `BaseVo<TIdentifier>`.

You can define Department class like this:

```
public class Department : BaseVo<int>
{

}
```